# how to use with app.config

Tags: c#

this is my app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="version" value="1.0.0."/> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

this is my code

```
txtVersion.Text = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["version"];
```

I get null value

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class:

```
txtVersion.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["version"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# Settings instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code, although `ConfigurationManager` now replaces `ConfigurationSettings`.

If you are running in Visual Studio, make sure your app.config has been copied to the bin\debug (or bin\release depending on if you are in release or debug mode) and has been correctly renamed to [yourappname].exe.config.

Make sure you have added the app.config to your project within Visual Studio (rather than just creating the file in the dir).  Alternatively, put the file manually in the bin\debug dir with the correct name as above and try again.